# Deleted file is still being accessed

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php script to delete an old instance of a csv file and upload a new one and a javascript function to read the file. It was working fine until I added the php to delete the old file, and now for some reason the javascript function always fetches the same file even when it's changed.

I've gone in and checked the data.csv file and it's the new file but the function still fetches the old one. And if I delete the file manually the function still mysteriously accesses the data.csv file... even though it's deleted.

This is the php:

```
<?php   
if(file_exists('upload/data.csv'))
{
    unlink('upload/data.csv'); // deletes file

}
$tmp_file_name = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$ok = move_uploaded_file($tmp_file_name, 'upload/data.csv');

?>
```

This is the javascript. Note: the variable "allText" will always be the contents of the old CSV file even if data.csv has changed or is deleted.

```
function LoadCSV(){

var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "http://****.com/mailer/upload/data.csv", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
    if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file.
      allText = txtFile.responseText; 
        ProcessCSV(allText);
        }
  }
}
txtFile.send(null);

}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably browser caching.
I like to use a random value in the url to trick the browser into thinking it is a different page:

Try this:

```
function LoadCSV() {

    var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    txtFile.open("GET", "http://****.com/mailer/upload/data.csv?nocache="+(Math.random()+'').replace('.',''), true);
    txtFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
            if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file.
                allText = txtFile.responseText;
                ProcessCSV(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    txtFile.send(null);

}
```

The get parameter nochache doesn't mean anything to the server or browser, but fools it into fetching a new resource every time, at the cost of losing browser caching altogether. Technically it's possible(although spectacularly unlikely) to get the same value twice, so you can add time in milliseconds or something if you want to make it totally foolproof.

Note that this will also bypass almost all other types of caches as well.